# Broken perspective projection matrix in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, matrix, perspectivecamera

I've been working on the transformations tutorial from [open.gl](http://open.gl/transformations) and am having trouble making my perspective projection matrix work. The tutorial uses GLM, but I chose to roll my own matrix math functions to try and learn the math a little better. Everything compiles fine (gcc -Wall), and my rotation and lookat matrix functions are working perfectly, but my perspective projection matrix causes a black screen with no OpenGL errors.

The projection matrix is (I think) supposed to be

```
/ cot(fovy/2)/aspect 0.0         0.0                                0.0 \
| 0.0                cot(fovy/2) 0.0                                0.0 |
| 0.0                0.0         (zfar + znear)/(znear - zfar)     -1.0 |
\ 0.0                0.0         (2 * zfar * znear)/(znear - zfar)  0.0 /
```

Interestingly, I can provide the intended effect with the matrix

```
/ cot(fovy/2)/aspect 0.0         0.0                            0.0 \
| 0.0                cot(fovy/2) 0.0                            0.0 |
| 0.0                0.0         (zfar + znear)/(znear - zfar) -1.0 |
\ 0.0                0.0         0.4                            1.0 /
```

[Here are the necessary source files.](https://bitbucket.org/cormac-obrien/misc-public/downloads) You'll need GLFW3 and SOIL to compile the code -- I've been using `gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw -lm -lSOIL transform.c -o transform`. I've tried to provide shorter (non-compiling) versions of the source below in case there are any glaring errors.

transform.c:

```
#include <math.h>
#define M_PI (3.14159265358979323846)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>

typedef struct mat4_t {
    float arr[16];
} mat4_t;

typedef struct vec3_t {
    float arr[3];
} vec3_t;

/* forward declarations... */

/* return a 4x4 'lookat' matrix to be multiplied by model space coords        */
mat4_t mat4mklook(const vec3_t eye, const vec3_t center, const vec3_t up) {
    /* check out the OpenGL gluLookAt documentation for an explanation */
    vec3_t f = vec3norm(vec3sub(center, eye));
    vec3_t up_ = vec3norm(up);
    vec3_t s = vec3cross(f, up_);
    vec3_t u = vec3cross(s, f);

    return (mat4_t) { { 
        s.arr[0],  s.arr[1],  s.arr[2], 0.0f,
        u.arr[0],  u.arr[1],  u.arr[2], 0.0f,
       -f.arr[0], -f.arr[1], -f.arr[2], 0.0f,
        0.0f,      0.0f,      0.0f,     1.0f
    } };
}

/* return a 4x4 persp. projection matrix to be multiplied by camera coords    */
mat4_t mat4mkproj(const float fovy, const float aspect, const float znear, const float zfar) {
    float f = 1 / tan(fovy / 2.0f);

    return (mat4_t){ {
        f/aspect, 0.0f,  0.0f,                      0.0f,
        0.0f,     f,     0.0f,                      0.0f,
        0.0f,     0.0f,  (zfar+znear)/(znear-zfar), (2*zfar*znear)/(znear-zfar),
        0.0f,     0.0f, -1.0f,                      0.0f
    } };
}

/* returns a 4x4 rotation matrix of magnitude 'th' about unit vector 'axis'   */
mat4_t mat4mkrot(const vec3_t axis, const float th) {
    const float uX = axis.arr[0];
    const float uY = axis.arr[1];
    const float uZ = axis.arr[2];
    const float sinth = sin(th);
    const float costh = cos(th);

    return (mat4_t) { {
        costh+pow(uX,2)*(1-costh), uX*uY*(1-costh)-uZ*sinth,  uX*uZ*(1-costh)+uY*sinth,  0.0,
        uY*uX*(1-costh)+uZ*sinth,  costh+pow(uY,2)*(1-costh), uY*uZ*(1-costh)-uX*sinth,  0.0,
        uZ*uX*(1-costh)-uY*sinth,  uZ*uY*(1-costh)+uX*sinth,  costh+pow(uZ,2)*(1-costh), 0.0,
        0.0,                       0.0,                       0.0,                       1.0
    } };
}

/* returns the product of matrices 'a' and 'b'                                */
mat4_t mat4mult(const mat4_t a, const mat4_t b) {
    mat4_t result;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        result.arr[i] = 0.0f;
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            result.arr[i] += a.arr[i / 4 + j] * b.arr[i % 4 + j * 4];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/* returns the cross product of vectors 'a' and 'b'                           */
vec3_t vec3cross(const vec3_t a, const vec3_t b) {
    return (vec3_t){ {
        a.arr[1] * b.arr[2] - a.arr[2] * b.arr[1],
        a.arr[2] * b.arr[0] - a.arr[0] * b.arr[2],
        a.arr[0] * b.arr[1] - a.arr[1] * b.arr[0]
    } };
}

/* returns a unit vector derived from vector 'v'                              */
vec3_t vec3norm(const vec3_t a) {
    vec3_t result;

    float mag;
    if((mag = sqrt(pow(a.arr[0], 2) + pow(a.arr[1], 2) + pow(a.arr[2], 2))) == 0.0f) {
        result = (vec3_t) {{0}};
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            result.arr[i] = a.arr[i] / mag;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/* return the vector difference 'a' - 'b'                                     */
vec3_t vec3sub(const vec3_t a, const vec3_t b) {
    vec3_t result;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        result.arr[i] = a.arr[i] - b.arr[i];
    }
    return result;
}

/* returns the dot product of vectors 'a' and 'b'                             */
float vec3dot(const vec3_t a, const vec3_t b) {
    return a.arr[0] * b.arr[0] +
           a.arr[1] * b.arr[1] +
           a.arr[2] * b.arr[2];
}

GLfloat vertices[] = {
  /* position       texture */
    -0.5f,  0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f
};

GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

int main() {
    glfwInit();

    /* context settings */

    /* window & context creation */
    GLFWwindow * const window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* glew initialization -- generates harmless error */
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glGetError();

    /* vertex setup */

    /* shader setup */

    /* vertex attribute setup */

    /* texture setup */

    GLint modeluni;
    { /* matrix uniform setup */
        modeluni = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");

        mat4_t viewmat = mat4mklook((vec3_t){{1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f}}, (vec3_t){{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}}, (vec3_t){{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}});
        GLint viewuni = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewuni, 1, GL_TRUE, viewmat.arr);

        mat4_t projmat = mat4mkproj(M_PI / 4.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
        GLint projuni = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projuni, 1, GL_TRUE, projmat.arr);
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        const GLuint error = glGetError();
        if(error) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", error);
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

        mat4_t modmat = mat4mkrot((vec3_t){{0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}, (glfwGetTime() / 2.0) * M_PI);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modeluni, 1, GL_TRUE, modmat.arr);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); 

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    /* delete opengl ids */

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

vert.glsl:

```
#version 330

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 Texcoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main() {
    Color = color;
    Texcoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

frag.glsl:

```
#version 330

in vec3 Color;
in vec2 Texcoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D texKitten;
uniform sampler2D texPuppy;

void main() {
    vec4 colKitten = texture(texKitten, Texcoord);
    vec4 colPuppy = texture(texPuppy, Texcoord);
    outColor = mix(colKitten, colPuppy, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Apparently "OpenGL assumes that the points in the scene are projected on the near clipping planes, rather than on a plane that lies one unit away from the camera position." http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/perspective-projection-matrix/ this means a slightly different matrix needs to be used. Also see Have a look at http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html the matrix seems to have a different form to yours.

Comment: I would recommend to have a look at the lessons from scratchapixel on this. It explains very clearly how this matrix is built, and also what happens in OpenGL as Salix suggested because you need to account for the near and far clipping planes.